# Responding checkbox with withItemResponse

Tags: google-apps-script

My problem is:

`const answers = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()-1); // Get the information from the sheet
formResponse[i].withItemResponse(items[19].asCheckboxItem().createResponse( answers[i][17])); // add a response to formResponse ,it is a checkbox item`

answers[i][17] is an object actually. It has the value "FALSE". I get this error:

```
Cannot find method createResponse(string).
```

Even if i write false/true or "false"/"true" or something else , createResponse rejects it with error. When i use boolean i take the same error with the boolean version. 
How should i add the checkbox as a response ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a weird way. Code:

`if(answers[i][17] == true)
  formResponse[i].withItemResponse(items[19].asCheckboxItem().createResponse( new Array(items[19].asCheckboxItem().getChoices()[0].getValue() )));`

The reason behind this:

You need to give the string array, not string itself. And string must be the checkbox title, not true or false. Because we could add more than one checkbox and when it comes to checkboxes responses, how could we choose which one is true or false? So i took the choices and since i have one choice, instead of making it string array in a loop i decide to use only the first item. Since i have one item, array has one element. But it is choice array, so i took the first string and i put it in a new array. Here it is, you have a string array. For multiple checking, you can create a loop that iterates the choice array and add their value(which is string) to a new array. Like:

```
var strArray = new Array(choiceArray.length);
for(var i=0; i < choiceArray.length; ++i)
  strArray[i] = choiceArray[i];
```

And you can disable some of the for letting it unchecked. It is just a way, you can do more efficient versions.

PS: I think that google apps script has things that enforce the developers to write non-efficient and too many lines of codes. But at the end, the fundamental system is working great and actually if some of us decide to use another language or framework, it could be much slower.